# What is the best way to provide sample applescripts with a macOS App distributed via AppStore

Tags: macos, installation, applescript, mac-app-store

I'm creating a macOS app which is scriptable. The app will be distributed via AppStore. I have some sample scripts. Some work directly without any change others need customisation before use. What would be the best way to provide these scripts. I thought about a menu item in the app to offer installation or provide the scripts only in documentation. I found no "best way" in the apple documentation. Is there a common way and I missed it?